# NullPointerException when setting a datasource for SQL SERVER 2008 in IntelliJ

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, intellij-idea, nullpointerexception, datasource

I'm trying to set a datasource in Intellij for SQL SERVER 2008 using sqljdbc4, and I receive an error window with java.lang.NullPointerException.

urls I tried: 
`jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\.:1433;databaseName=mobitrack`
`jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=mobitrack`
but same outcome.

Any idea as to what might cause the exception?

Thank you in advance.

Here's a screenshot of the exception:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxqQe.png

idea.log:

```
2013-03-22 17:13:12,770 [7171087]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - "c:\program files\jetbrains\intellij idea 11.0\jre\jre\bin\java" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 11.0\plugins\DatabaseSupport\lib\jdbc-console.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 11.0\lib\util.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 11.0\lib\annotations.jar;D:\sqljdbc4-4.0.2206.100.jar" com.intellij.persistence.database.console.RemoteJdbcServer com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver 
2013-03-22 17:13:13,532 [7171849]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Port/ID:30598/RemoteDriverImple39ef7c1 
2013-03-22 17:13:14,333 [7172650]  ERROR - j.javaee.dataSource.DataSource - null 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.intellij.javaee.dataSource.DatabaseSchemaLoader.getSchemasToLoad(DatabaseSchemaLoader.java:77)
    at com.intellij.javaee.dataSource.DataSource$1.perform(DataSource.java:324)
    at com.intellij.javaee.dataSource.DataSource$1.perform(DataSource.java:317)
    at com.intellij.javaee.dataSource.DataSource.performJdbcOperation(DataSource.java:257)
    at com.intellij.javaee.dataSource.DataSource.refreshMetaData(DataSource.java:317)
    at com.intellij.javaee.module.view.dataSource.DataSourceUiUtil$4.run(DataSourceUiUtil.java:138)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$TaskRunnable.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:457)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$5.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:276)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:206)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:169)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:617)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$6.run(ApplicationImpl.java:410)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:135)
2013-03-22 17:13:14,334 [7172651]  ERROR - j.javaee.dataSource.DataSource - IntelliJ IDEA 11.0  Build #IU-111.69 
2013-03-22 17:13:14,334 [7172651]  ERROR - j.javaee.dataSource.DataSource - JDK: 1.6.0_29 
2013-03-22 17:13:14,334 [7172651]  ERROR - j.javaee.dataSource.DataSource - VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 
2013-03-22 17:13:14,334 [7172651]  ERROR - j.javaee.dataSource.DataSource - Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc. 
2013-03-22 17:13:14,335 [7172652]  ERROR - j.javaee.dataSource.DataSource - OS: Windows 7 
2013-03-22 17:13:14,353 [7172670]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Please [provide idea.log](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23352446).

Comment: Try IDEA [11.1.5](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-1228) or IDEA [12.1](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+12.1+EAP). Your version is ancient. Also check that you have the [latest JDBC driver](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11774) or try the [jTDS driver](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/) instead.

Comment: I updated IDEA and it worked thank you. And by the way, the problem was the relationships between the tables somehow the old IDEA didn't recognize them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that URL is not correct.  Try this:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=mobitrack
```

First things first: Is the SQL Server listener up and listening on port 1433?

Open a command shell and type `netstat -a`.  If you don't see `LISTENING` on port 1433, Java won't be able to connect.

`NullPointerException` doesn't mean you didn't connect.  I'd bet that something else is wrong.

Print the stack trace.  It tells you the file and line number at which you had a null reference.  Step through in a debugger and see what and why.

I don't know where you got that JDBC driver JAR, but the one I use for SQL Server is named sqljdbc.jar.  Try updating the driver JAR and see if that helps.

I can do this with IntelliJ, so you can, too.

Comment: Try 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.